# "({\tt \\/}) to make the" will cause an error of an extra "}" in TeX

Tags: pdftex

On the page 27 of the book **TeX for the Impatient**, there is
`({\tt \\/}) to make the`

When I input these into the tex file and then run with TeX, there is an error:

```
! Argument of \\ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.1 ({\tt \\/}
              ) to make the
?
```

[image]

What is the reason?

---

If add this before,

```
\chardef \\ = ‘\\ % Let \\ denote a backslash.
```

There is a new error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ^^e2
l.1 \chardef \\ = ^^e2
                      ^^80^^98\\ % Let \\ denote a backslash.
```

Comment: please clarify  your question with an example, the plain tex file `({\tt \/}) to make the
\bye` runs without error.

Comment: oh your error message shows `\\/` but your quote is showing `\/`  which did you intend?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `({\tt \\/}) to make the \bye` will cause the error from here. Are you using **TeX** to run it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  The quote will change `\\ ` to `\ `. I used the `\\/`.

Comment: I don't have the book but I would guess `\/` was intended not `\\/`

Comment: oh I forgot the book is free now..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is the book: https://tug.ctan.org/info/impatient/book.pdf . Wasn't it ever free?

Comment: @campa  Okay. I can't image that such famous book could have errors.

Comment: all books have errors (but this is not one of them:-)

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. I should've read the whole paragraph

Comment: The backtick should be a grave accent (U+0060), you've pasted here a left single quotation mark (U+2018)

Comment: @campa usual problem of pasting from pdf with legacy encodings where it guesses some unicode text.....

Comment: @Y.zeng no the book was not free originally, see the preface: Preface to the free edition: This book was originally published in 1990 by Addison-Wesley. In 2003, it was declared out of print and Addison-Wesley generously reverted all rights to us, the authors. We decided to make the book available in source form, under the GNU Free Documentation License

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more complete quote is

[image]

so the fragment shown is assuming the definition

```
\chardef \\ = `\\ % Let \\ denote a backslash.
```

but you are using the standard plain tex definition of `\\`  which takes an argument delimited by `pt`)

```
\chardef\\ = `\\ % Let \\ denote a backslash.
({\tt \\/}) to make the
\bye
```

runs without error.

[image]

Comment: `\chardef \\ = ‘\\ % Let \\ denote a backslash.` will cause an error so I omit it.

Comment: you need an ascii backtick `\`` not a typographic left quote

Comment: @Y.zeng I updated with working example

Comment: What is the meaning of ```\chardef \\ = `\\```, and I just copied it. Why the author not set the font to one which is copied without changed backtick?

Comment: @Y.zeng `\chardef` defines a character by giving a number in the font (it's how `\%` or `\&` etc are defined). `\`\\ ` is the ascii number for a backslash, you often see the backtick used toget a number in constructs like `\catcode\`\\=12`  but here it is on the right hand side of the `=`

Comment: @Y.zeng minor text updates and showing image of intended output

Comment: The author give the `\\ ` a ascii number. But why did he do this and for what?

Comment: no he defined `\\ ` to print a `\ ` just as `\&` is defined to print a `&` @Y.zeng

Comment: @Y.zeng see the output I show at the end of the answer `\\/` produces the equivalent of latex `\verb|\/|`

Comment: There's a catch. Every time I copy the code from the pdf, I need to replace this symbol, sometimes it is replaced by backtick and sometimes it is replaced by '.  How  to make it automatically replaced?

Comment: using a modern latex pdflatex format there could be a to unicode map to make sure that that ` cut and paste as ` not U+2018 but with the pdf as it is (which as noted in the preface is made with a copy of eplain that was old in 2003 and is ancient now, you rely on your pdf reader to make the right guess. @Y.zeng

Comment: A little diffficult to understand. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: @Y.zeng classic tex encodings with only 127 character did not treat `\`` and `‘` as separate characters, just a font change some having a curly quote and some a straight one.  So if copying from a pdf of that era to a modern Unicode system that does have separate straight backtick and a curly left quote character your pdf reader has to guess which one you want. For most people (who are not writing tex code) getting a curly left quote is a good guess.

Comment: So, do you mean at the that time, the system is not a unicode one? What's the format of the system at that time? the ASCII?

Comment: plain tex using classic computer modern fonts  is _still_ not unicode.  The fonts only have 127 characters so not even European accented letters and no cyrillic or Greek or CJK   or typographic quotation marks...

Comment: So, we can't make file containing Greek of CJK and so on directly from plain tex?

Comment: you can use plain tex with a unicode tex eg xetex, or with pdftex you can use the characters in non standard encodings but then for example a greek alpha will look OK on paper but would cut and paste as `a`  (onscreen cut and paste was not considered in tex's design)  using legacy encodings it is possible to give internal `tounicode` pdf mapping tables so that cut and paste works again, but that has to be set up in the tex macros for the format and that wasn't done back then (as unicode was less important and the machines would not have had spare memory for the tables with the mapping) @Y.zeng

Comment: but I stop here this is way off topic for this question post

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.